# Saving active view into ArcGIS Pro project using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I have a desirable requirement to be able to set the active view (Layout, Map, Basemap, etc) in an ArcGIS Pro project using ArcPy.

However the [ArcGISProject class](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/arcgisproject-class.htm#M2_GUID-1117B216-CE8B-47A9-998B-6143907D3165) does not seem to provide a method to do this.

I would like to be able to make sure that a particular Layout in my ArcGIS Pro project is the view that a copy of my project (made using the saveACopy method) opens to when I give it to someone.

Is it possible to do this by any other means from ArcPy?

If I were using ArcPy with ArcMap the equivalent would be accessible in the `activeView` property of the `MapDocument` class.

Comment: By "active view" you mean the map or layout tab that is enabled?  Is it possible to do in ArcMap (between Data view and Layout)?

Comment: @Midavalo Yes - that is what I mean by the active view.  Using ArcPy with ArcMap it is accessible in the activeView property of the MapDocument class.

Comment: I can't find anything that looks similar in the 2.0 beta either.  It appears that it's been removed rather than moved, as `project` (or `map` or `layout`) would be the places I'd expect to see it, but can't find it in any of those.

Comment: Searching for "activeview" in the [ArcGIS Pro documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/search/?q=activeView&collection=all&product=arcgis-pro&version=pro1.4&language=en) yields zero results.  Also, I can't find it in any [classes](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/alphabeticallistofclasses.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have submitted an ArcGIS Idea for this:

[Saving active view into ArcGIS Pro project using ArcPy](https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/13576-saving-active-view-into-arcgis-pro-project-using-arcpy):

> I have a desirable requirement to be able to set the active view
>   (Layout, Map, Basemap, etc) in an ArcGIS Pro project using ArcPy.
>
> However the [ArcGISProject class](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/arcgisproject-class.htm#M2_GUID-1117B216-CE8B-47A9-998B-6143907D3165) does not seem to provide a method to
>   do this.
>
> I would like to be able to make sure that a particular Layout in my
>   ArcGIS Pro project is the view that a copy of my project (made using
>   the saveACopy method) opens to when I give it to someone.
>
> If I were using ArcPy with ArcMap the equivalent would be accessible
>   in the activeView property of the MapDocument class.